# Find Top 5 Customers for Beverages based on their total purchase value SQL

Tags: sql, dataset

Here is the link to the Data Set.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc

I have been trying to solve this but couldn't find a way to get the total purchase value while grouping with the customer table

Comment: Please add everything about your question *to your question* not an external link, and include your current attempts; see the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
SELECT c.customerid,
       Sum(p.price)
FROM   customers AS c
       INNER JOIN orders AS o
               ON o.customerid = c.customerid
       INNER JOIN orderdetails AS od
               ON od.orderid = o.orderid
       INNER JOIN products AS p
               ON p.productid = od.productid
GROUP  BY c.customerid
ORDER  BY Sum(p.price) DESC
LIMIT  5
```

Just following on from your quantity comment...

```
SELECT c.customerid,
       Sum(p.price),
       Sum(p.price * od.quantity)
FROM   customers AS c
       INNER JOIN orders AS o
               ON o.customerid = c.customerid
       INNER JOIN orderdetails AS od
               ON od.orderid = o.orderid
       INNER JOIN products AS p
               ON p.productid = od.productid
GROUP  BY c.customerid
ORDER  BY Sum(p.price) DESC
LIMIT  5
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this i also reached this conclusion as well but to find the total purchase value we still need to multiply each "price" from "products" table to "quantity" in OrderDetails Table and its kinda confusing. i thought of using temp table or subquary

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a Common Table Expression (CTE) as, in my experience, it helps with scalability/maintenance down the road and easily enables you to see what the data is under the hood if you wanted to simply run the CTE itself.

I join the Customer to the Order to get the OrderID
I join the Order to OrderDetails to get the ProductID and Order Quantity
I join the OrderDetails to Products to get the Price
I join the Categories to filter for just Beverages

All this is wrapped as a CTE (similar to a subquery), on top of which I can now aggregate at the Customer level and sequence by Order Value in a descending fashion.

```
with beverage_orders_cte as(
  SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
  , od.OrderDetailID, od.ProductID, od.Quantity
  , p.ProductName, p.Price
  , od.Quantity * p.Price as OrderVal
  ,cat.CategoryName FROM Customers c
      inner join Orders o
          on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
      inner join OrderDetails od
          on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
      inner join Products p 
              on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
      inner join Categories cat
              on p.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID and cat.CategoryID = 1
)
select CustomerName, SUM(OrderVal) as Revenue 
From beverage_orders_cte
Group by CustomerName
Order by Revenue desc
Limit 5
```

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Useful for respecting `CategoryID`. Suggestion: `join Categories cat on p.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID and cat.CategoryName = 'Beverages'` - you don't need relation cat when you *know* `CategoryID = 1`.

Comment: If the query for just Beverages is the end-all, be all, sure. I left it as an ID for scalability so that it can easily be changed rather than typing out names. In a perfect world, it would probably be best kept outside the CTE in the aggregate query itself (or more practically, in an application that would filter for it). It really comes down to use-case/preference.

Comment: Prefer selecting just useful entities/records over transferring more and filtering out the irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best optimized code.
Please try with this.

```sql
SELECT CustomerID, Count(Quantity * Price) AS Total
FROM Orders, OrderDetails, Products
Where Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID AND Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
Group by CustomerID
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 5
```